# Basis of V$TIMEZONE_NAMES oracle view

Tags: sql, database, oracle, timezone

I am looking up for some time zones in the V$TIMEZONE_NAMES  view but could not find those time zones listed in the oracle view. Some of the example of timezone I am not able to see are: Europe/Andorra, Asia/Colombo. These are just 2 examples. I have list of around 80 such timezone names.
Can anybody tell me how do i get these timezones added to the view. I understand that it is a oracle internal view. Thus basically what I am asking how do oracle know the timezones it has to list and what should I do if I need to get a missing time zone added so that it shows up in V$TIMEZONE_NAMES view.
Thanks

Comment: Check which time zone file is used at your database, see [Choosing a Time Zone File](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch4datetime.htm#NLSPG004)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Good point, `version` of  `v$timezone_file` is important.

Comment: Also `FILENAME` of `v$timezone_file` important. Perhaps you use the short file named `timezone_<version_number>.dat` instead of the large file named `timezlrg_<version_number>.dat`

Answer (score 0):

> I am not able to see are: Europe/Andorra, Asia/Colombo.

You might be missing something, I can see both the **timezones**:

```
SQL> SELECT tzname,
  2         tzabbrev
  3  FROM   V$TIMEZONE_NAMES
  4  WHERE  tzname IN ('Europe/Andorra', 'Asia/Colombo');

TZNAME               TZABBREV
-------------------- --------------------
Asia/Colombo         LMT
Asia/Colombo         MMT
Asia/Colombo         IST
Asia/Colombo         IHST
Asia/Colombo         LKT
Europe/Andorra       LMT
Europe/Andorra       WET
Europe/Andorra       CET
Europe/Andorra       CEST

9 rows selected.
```

`V$TIMEZONE_NAMES` is actually a **public synonym** for the `V_$TIMEZONE_NAMES` **view**. You could also query **SYS.V_$TIMEZONE_NAMES**.

Also, depending on your **database version**, you will have a different **timezone file**. I am on Oracle `12.1` and I have the following file:

```
SQL> SELECT filename, version FROM v$timezone_file;

FILENAME                VERSION
-------------------- ----------
timezlrg_18.dat              18
```

Your **filename** and **version** might be different. With every release Oracle issues patches for these files.

Comment: Running same query in my DB doesn't give me same results. Unfortunately I am a java guy and not a Oracle expert. Thus want to know how do I get the same results as you are getting.  This is what I am getting                                                                              Asia/Calcutta IST
Asia/Dacca IST
Asia/Dhaka IST
Asia/Gaza IST
Asia/Jerusalem IST
Asia/Karachi IST
Asia/Tel_Aviv IST
Atlantic/Reykjavik IST
Eire IST
Europe/Belfast IST
Europe/Dublin IST
Iceland IST
Israel IST

Comment: All depends upoon the timezone file residing in the database server. Please check that and confirm

Comment: The file name is timezlrg.dat and version is 4. My database is Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.5.0 - 64bi